# MikTeX error: Invalid control sequence

Tags: errors, miktex

I've recently installed MikTeX 2.9 for Windows 7, 64. After installation I try to compile an IEEE template downloaded from their website. I get the following error:

miktex-pdftex.exe: Invalid control sequence.

I've tried many things I've read online but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: please post the _exact_ error lines from the `.log` file. You can add them to the question and use the `{}` button to mark then as a code section.

Comment: I don't think a log file is ever generated. Where do I look to make sure?

Comment: in the folder with your document. How are you running latex? on the commandline `pdflatex file` or using some tex IDE/editor?

Comment: I don't have miktex but google suggests this: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=11760

Comment: No log file in there. I'm running the MikteX alone on pdftex or any other option. They all give "Invalid control sequrence" error. I have Texmaker which gives me the "log file not found" error and therefore does not compile.

Comment: Did you install MiKTeX first, or TeXmaker?

Comment: MikTex, then restarted the pc, then Texmaker.

Comment: The .log file appears at the bottom of the editor window. You can ask for selecting all and copying.

Comment: Bernard, using texmaker, nothing is generated at the bottom, only the "log file not found" error. Using TeXnicCenter, I get 3 error at the bottom of the window: 1- pdflatex.exe: Invalid control sequence, 2- bibtex.exe: Invalid control sequence, and 3- makeindex.exe: Invalid control sequence.

Comment: Did you try the fix suggested in the link David Carlisle posted? (I don't have MiKTeX either but your problem certainly seems similar.)

Comment: cfr, I've tried that fix. It did not help. When I try to build the formats I get the "MikTex configuration utility failed" error. Kurt, yes I installed by running as an administrator and the installation went ok. I cannot compile the "Hello World!" example, I receive the same Invalid control sequence error.

Comment: Try on a command line `initexmf -u`. Btw: there are often more problems with (multi user) admin installations then with single user installation in a user account.